# Как проверить ВСЮ строку на соответсвие регулярному выражению?

Tags: javascript

```
let str = '10,,';
let re = /[0-9]+([\,]?[0-9]+)?/;
console.log(re.test(str));
```

В данном примере проверяется наличие ЛЮБОГО совпадения с указанным регулярным выражением. Мне же нужно проверить ВСЮ строку на соответствие этому регулярному выражению. Например как это делает аттрибут `pattern` в **html** или функция `preg_match()` в **PHP**. Как проверить ВСЮ строку в `javascript`??? Есть ли готовая функция???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте спереди регулярки символ `^`, а сзади `$`.

https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-anchors